# sizeof void pointer

Tags: c, void-pointers

why is `sizeof` void pointer `2` ?

Comment: Because that's the size of the pointer in your system. The size is expressed with respect to the size of a `char`. `char` is usually 8 bit long, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: It isn't. Or more specifically: It doesn't have to be.

Comment: ya..u r right. its  platform dependent

Comment: (off topic) I suggest you switch to Windows 10 because DOS is probably not the best coding platform :-)

Answer (score 51):

The size of a `void*` is a platform dependent value.  Typically it's value is 4 or 8 bytes for 32 and 64 bit platforms respectively.  If you are getting 2 as the value then your likely running on a 16 bit coding platform (or potentially have a coding error).

Could you post the code you are using and some more information about your environment / operating system?

Comment: He's probably running Turbo C under 16 bit DOS

Comment: @Paul, thanks updated for 16 bit OS's.  I thought it much more likely that it was an error instead of people still using 16 bit OS's but that may be a poor assumption.

Comment: for some reason a lot of colleges (especially those in India) still seem to use things like Turbo C and 16 bit DOS (as well as some very bad text books), which is why we tend to see a lot of questions on SO and elsewhere with e.g. `void main()` and assumptions about sizeof(void *) being 2, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Per the [online C standard (n1256 draft)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 27  **A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.**39) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
> as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
> alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same
> representation or alignment requirements.

As to why void and char pointers have a size of 2 on your system, I suspect that's because you're on a 16-bit platform.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer stores a memory address that points to something else. 
The size of a pointer depends on your platform. On a 32 bit platform you need 32 bits or four bytes to store a memory address so sizeof any pointer will return 4.

If sizeof(void*) is 2 you're probably running on a 16 bit platform.

Comment: sizeof returns the size with respect to the size of the `char`. The `char` type usually is 8 bit long, but doesn't have to be. I'm not saying I know such a system, but it's not impossible to have a system, where `char` is 32 bit long and in such a system `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)` all can be equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

As JaredPar already pointed out, this is platform dependant. 
To put it differently: How many bits does the used CPU use for memory-addressing? For 16bit adresses you would get a size of 2 bytes. Are you compiling code for a 16bit microcontroller?

Comment: Yes, the "microcontroller" Intel 8088, used in the IBM PC. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Size of a Pointer is equal to the size of an Integer . It can be 2 bytes in a 16bit compiler and 4 bytes in 32 bit compiler and 8 in 64 bit compiler.

`void *ptr`, `int *ptr` and `char *ptr` will give you same size but if you do `ptr++` , the corresponding pointer will jump according to there data types. ie 1 position in `void` and `char` case. Similarly 4 positions in `int` case.

Comment: Size of a void pointer and size of an int are not the same thing. Using gcc on my OSX machine, `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(void *) == 8`

Comment: And even before today's 64 bit architectures, many older architectures supported 32 bit pointers for global addressing, while still only having 16 bit `int`s (e.g. sometimes all registers were only 16 bits, so `int`, which is supposed to handle the "fast native integer type" could only be 16 bits, while non-local pointer addresses were stored in a pair of 16 bit registers to achieve a 64 bit address space). Some common standards (especially ILP32) make `int` and pointers the same size, but there are [3+ standards which don't](https://unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html).