# Why is sizeof(int) different than sizeof(int*)?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

I am wondering why in the following program `sizeof(int)` returns a different value than `sizeof(int*)`.

Here is the small program:

```
int main(){
    std::cout<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
    std::cout<<sizeof(int*)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
4
8
```

Till now I remember the size of a integer pointer is 4byte(gcc compiler). How can I check the correct size of a pointer? Is it computer dependent?

I am running ubuntu 12.04

```
# lsb_release -a

Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 
Release:    12.04 
Codename:   precise
```

Is the size of pointer is not constant(standard size)  8 bytes.

Comment: 64 bit Operating System?

Comment: @ahenderson- Are you sure that all pointers are guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: Also add the output of `uname -a` or `file <your-compiled-binary>`

Comment: FYI, there is no "Standard Size".

Comment: @ahenderson: Pointers to different types don't have to be the same size.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth : Could I see an example in code. I'm not too sure on the issue now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof void pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853312/sizeof-void-pointer)

Comment: Its simple.  int is 4 bytes because its a 32-bit value.  int* is 8 bytes because its an address in memory.  It still only holds 32-bits of information.

Comment: @ahenderson There's no guarantee that all pointers have the same size.  I've worked on machines where `char*` was larger than `int*`, and on machines (Intel 8086) where function pointers had a different size from data pointers.

Comment: @ahenderson: It's platform-dependent.  The canonical examples are [near and far pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer), or heterogeneous code and data pointers on a Harvard architecture.

Comment: @Ramhound: "It still only holds 32-bits of information."  What?

Comment: Important question: why would you have expected them to be the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The size of an `int` and an `int*` are completely compiler and hardware dependent.  If you're seeing eight bytes used in an `int*`, you likely have 64-bit hardware, which translates into eight bytes per pointer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "You likely have a 64-bit operating system."  Indeed, but more importantly, your process is likely a 64-bit process.  :-)

Comment: I'd like to add, that the only type whose size is defined by standard is `char`. `sizeof(char)` is always `1`

Comment: @LihO: The size of a `char` is not actually defined by the standard, but `sizeof` express is results in _number of chars_.

Comment: @K-ballo: I think that was true before C99 since [C99 section 6.5.3.4](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html) says: *"The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand"*.

Comment: @Liho: Unless they have fixed the number of bits in a char _(never gonna happen)_... a `char` is one _byte_ but a _byte_ size is implementation defined.

Answer (score 10):

`sizeof(char) == 1`

There are no other guarantees(*).

In practice, pointers will be size 2 on a 16-bit system, 4 on a 32-bit system, and 8 on a 64-bit system.

---

(*) See the comment of James Kanze.

Comment: `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)` is also guaranteed.  As is `sizeof(float) <= sizeof(double) <= sizeof(long double)`.  (There's also a guarantee that all sizes are integral, but that's more or less understood.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Wanting to be pedantic yes, good comment. I tried to write the answer as clear as possible according to the type of question and questioner.

Comment: Pointers are generally 2 bytes on 8-bit systems too, such as Arduino Uno (ATmega 328 microcontroller).

Answer (score 5):

The size of a pointer is system, compiler, and architecture-dependent. On 32-bit systems it will typically be 32 bits while on 64-bit systems they will typically be 64 bits.

If you're trying to store a pointer into an integer for later restoration into the pointer again you can use the type `intptr_t` which is an integral type big enough to hold (I believe) normal (non-function) pointer types.

Answer (score 2):

> For 32-bit systems, the 'de facto' standard is ILP32 - that is, int,
>   long and pointer are all 32-bit quantities.
>
> For 64-bit systems, the primary Unix 'de facto' standard is LP64 -
>   long and pointer are 64-bit (but int is 32-bit). The Windows 64-bit
>   standard is LLP64 - long long and pointer are 64-bit (but long and int
>   are both 32-bit).
>
> At one time, some Unix systems used an ILP64 organization.
>
> None of these de facto standards is legislated by the C standard
>   (ISO/IEC 9899:1999), but all are permitted by it.

and

> If you are concerned with portability, or you want the name of the
>   type reflects the size, you can look at the header , where
>   the following macros are available:
>
> `int8_t int16_t int32_t int64_t`
>
> `int8_t` is guaranteed to be 8 bits, and `int16_t` is guaranteed to be 16
>   bits, etc.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc).

Comment: There's no guarantee that `int8_t` etc. exist.  For maximum portability, just use `int`, unless you know you need something larger, and validate your input.

Comment: @JamesKanze: ??? <inttypes.h> is fairly standard. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html

Comment: @OAOD `<stdint.h>` is standard C and C++ header in which these types are defined, and in `<stdint.h>`, `int8_t` et al. are marked as optional.  In the C standard, I think they are "required" if the hardware supports them; that is at any rate the intent.  But they must be exact size types, and the signed types must be 2's complement.  On machines which don't have 8 bit bytes, or which aren't 2's complement, they won't be defined.  (Posix requires them, which limits the hardware on which it can be implemented.)