# How can a pointer to double that is 4 Bytes point to double that is 8 Bytes?

Tags: c++, pointers, double, 32bit-64bit

I have this naive question:

A `double` is 8 Bytes even on 32 bit machines, also `long long`, and we know that the pointer size on that implementation is just 4 Bytes. Because that has a relationship with the processor's register size. So a processor register must be able to address any data type.

Here is my code, run with compiler flag `-m32`:

```
std::cout << "size of double: " << sizeof(double) << '\n'; // 8
std::cout << "size of double*: " << sizeof(double*) << '\n'; // 4
```

- So how can a pointer to `double` of `4 Bytes` point to `8 Bytes` (`double object`)?
- On 64 bit systems the size of a pointer is 8 Bytes so it is OK. Does this mean `double` works more effectively on 64 bit systems than on 32 bit ones?

Comment: A pointer contains the memory address of something else. The size of something else doesn't change its address or the ability for a pointer of any size to point to it.

Comment: As an analogy: an address of a house is not as big as the house itself

Comment: @Lala5th Perhaps [Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_long_place_names) might not fit on a small house? 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is sizeof(int) different than sizeof(int\*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984659/why-is-sizeofint-different-than-sizeofint)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica But 32 bit pointers don't fit in `char` either ;)

Comment: @Lala5th Unless the `char` is 32 or 64-bit.  C does support such rare machines.

Comment: @Lala5th • sizeof(char) will = 1 and can be 64-bit on an architecture where each byte is 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how can a pointer to `double` of `4 Bytes` point to `8 Bytes` (`double object`)?

Because the "pointer" is different from what's being "pointed to".

Think about it: Your "pointer" can point to a double ... a float ... a char.

> Does this mean `double` works more effectively on 64 bit systems than on 32 bit ones?

No.  It merely means that the 64-bit machine can direct access a *larger address space*.

Here's a good tutorial on pointers:

[Pointers in C Programming: What is Pointer, Types & Examples](https://www.guru99.com/c-pointers.html)

Here's a good article on "memory addressing":

[Virtual address spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces)

Comment: "A: No. It merely means that the 64-bit machine can direct access a larger address space." Does it mean that direct access is more effective than on 32 bit implementations?

Comment: Please read the articles I cited.  Short answer: No.  An 8-bit CPU can address at most 256 bytes of memory at a time.  The earliest PCs were 8-bit; they could only accommodate tiny programs.  The original IBM PC was 16-bit, and supported "segments".   It allowed DOS programs to use a entire megabyte of memory.  Today's processors can accommodate gigabytes - or exabytes of memory.  That's the difference...

Comment: @paulsm4 most 8-bit MCUs can address **more than 256 bytes of memory**, at least in the instruction space [How can 8-bit processor support more than 256 bytes of RAM?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/57950/27052)

Comment: @phuclv - I was trying not to "overcomplicate" the answer.  But you're correct.  The "early PCs" I mentioned (for example, Apple II and Commodore PET) used 8-bit Motorola 6502 processors.  But they had  a 16-bit address bus, hence could access 64K of RAM.  Different "address modes" allowed the CPU to support 16 bit addressing. 
 Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502#Addressing) or [here](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~verts/cmpsci201/spr_2004/Lecture_02_2004-01-30_The_6502_processor.pdf) for details.